# How to make sense of "are precisely as the analysis in (80a/b/c) would lead us to expect"?

Tags: meaning

From [Andrew Radford. (2004). English Syntax: An Introduction. p.77.].

> If *we* is a first person determiner, *you* is a second person determiner
> and *ø* is a third person determiner, the grammaticality judgments in
> (79a/b/c) above are precisely as the analysis in (80a/b/c) would lead
> us to expect.

I think it has the same meaning with

> If *we* is a first person determiner, *you* is a second person determiner
> and *ø* is a third person determiner, the grammaticality judgments in
> (79a/b/c) above are precise as the analysis in (80a/b/c) would lead
> us to expect [that the grammaticality judgments in (79a/b/c) above are precise].

Comment: Why even question the sentence written by a grammarian? lead us to expect makes sense. are precise does not here.

Comment: *...are precisely as the analysis would lead us to expect* = *...are **exactly the same as** we expect [after seeing the analysis].*

Answer (score 2):

It’s saying that the judgments about whether one set of utterances are grammatical can be made based exactly on the analogous judgments about the other utterances’ gramatticality. The judgments are **precisely as** (in other words, **of exactly the nature that**) we would expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

If I say, "That cheap pair of calipers has so much slop, they're not good for measuring anything", and then when you take them in hand and see for yourself that my opinion of them was accurate, you could say:

> They are *precisely* as you have said.

And the meaning would be "*just* as you said" or "*exactly* as you have said".  You are saying that I was not mistaken at all in my opinion of them.

But if you would say this instead:

> They are *precise* as you have said.

I would reply, "But I told you they are **not** precise!"

Comment: What is omitted? Can it be expanded to "They are [ ] precisely as you have said they to be [ ]."?

Comment: What is omitted  is "**are** [not good for measuring anything]" as you have *claimed them* to be [not good for measuring anything]" or "... as you said *they were* [not good for measuring anything]".  Note: "said they *to be*"  is ungrammatical.